# Why this composition program asks for inputting values twice?

Tags: c++

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "birthday.h"
#include "people.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    birthday object;
    people object2;
}
```

birthday.h

```
#ifndef BIRTHDAY_H_
#define BIRTHDAY_H_

class birthday
{
public:
    birthday();
    void printdate();
private:
    int d,m,y;
};
#endif
```

birthday.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "birthday.h"
using namespace std;

birthday::birthday()
{
    cout << "Input date";
    cin >> d;
    cout << "Input month";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "Input year";
    cin >> y;
    cout << d << "/" << m << "/" << y << "\n";
}
void birthday::printdate()
{
    cout << d << "/" << m << "/" << y << "\n";
}
```

people.h

```
#ifndef PEOPLE_H_
#define PEOPLE_H_
#include <string>
#include "birthday.h"

class people
{
public:
    people();
private:
    birthday dateofbirth;
    std::string x;
};
#endif
```

people.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "people.h"
#include "birthday.h"
using namespace std;

people::people()
{
    cout << "Enter the string";
    cin >> x;
    cout << x << "  was born on ";
    dateofbirth.printdate();
}
```

The program works very well except it asks for date, month and year twice. I could not find where the root of the problem is. When I run it, it asks to enter date, then month and later year. The cycle is once again repeated and then the program works as it should.

Comment: `main()` creates a birthday object, and a people object that has a private birthday object as a member. In other words, the constructor is run twice, once for each birthday object.

Comment: you have created two objects of this `class birthday` 1st in main and 2nd in `class people`. You have taken input in constructor so it ask two times for input. You can modify People class construct to take birthday object and then call print on that object. something like people(birthday obj).

Comment: You create `birthday` twice: in `main()` and in `people.h`

Comment: Aside: never ask user for inputs in ctors... It's too weird and a very bad practice... Ask for input and then use values as arguments to ctors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default constructor for `birthday` prompts the user for and takes input. Two birthdays are instantiated.

```
int main()
{
    birthday object; << here
    people object2; << and here
}
```

Why in `object2`? Because `people` contains a member of type `birthday`.

```
class people {
public:
    people();
private:
    birthday dateofbirth; <<because of here
    std::string x;
};
```

The solution is to not take input in the constructor or provide a constructor that does not take input. I suggest something like:

```
class birthday {
public:
    birthday(int day, int month, int year): 
            d(day),m(month),y(year),
    {
    }

    void printdate();
private:
    int d,m,y; // seriously consider using more descriptive names.
};
```

and

```
class people {
public:
    people(int day, int month, int year): 
        dateofbirth(day, month, year)
    {
    }
private:
    birthday dateofbirth;
    std::string x;
};
```

The input is taken from the user, validated, and then used to construct the `people` instance which in turn constructs the `birthday`.

The `:` in the constructors tells the compiler that a [Member Initializer List](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) follows. This allows you to construct non-trivial members before entering the body of the constructor and pass arguments to constructors for inherited classes.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are creating 2 birthday objects.

One in your main, and one as a member of People.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing Input/Output in the constructor of `birthday` class. And you have two `birthday` objects being created in your program.

1. In your `int main()` function
2. As a member of the `people` object.

You should consider moving your IO work to a member function. So that you do your IO when needed.

```
int main()
{
   birthday object;
   object.get_input();     //Do your IO
   people object2;
}
```

---

*PS: As much as possible **avoid** doing IO in constructors, there are exceptional cases of cause, but for your own use-case, its simply bad design*. Just as you have a `void birthday::printdate()` member function responsible for printing the date, you should equally move your Input operations in a similarly named function like say `void birthday::get_input()`.